# Intercepting HttpErrorResponse and redirecting user to login page

Tags: angular, typescript, http, interceptor

I'm trying to redirect the user to the login page every time the login fails. I've set up an interceptor to handle Http responses:

```
export class HttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor { 
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {}, (err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        console.log("http error intercepted")
      }
    });
  }
}
```

However, the error I get is "property do does not exist on type observable>". I'm also confused as to how I would redirect the user back to the login page from the interceptor. How can I address this? Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what you are trying to accomplish, but this uses `pipe` and the newer `tap` operator, which is the replacement for the `do` operator.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent,
    HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap(
        event => event instanceof HttpResponse ? 'succeeded' : '',
        error => {
          if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            console.log('http error intercepted')
          }
        })
    );
  }
}
```

FYI: This compiles, but I have not tested it.